# Algebraic invariants of higher order tensors

Tags: multilinear-algebra, invariant-theory, tensor-decomposition

Let's call an *algebraic invariant* (under the action of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$) a tensor of order $N$ to an algebraic combination of the components of that tensor. In other words, a homogeneous polynomial in the components of the tensor.

- For $N = 2$ algebraic invariants are well known: given a second-order tensor, defined over vector spaces of dimension $n$, it is very simple to see that there are $n$ independent invariants that are coefficients of the Cayley–Hamilton polynomial (linear or trace invariant, quadratic invariant, and n-degree invariant or determinant). Any other algebraic invariant can be computed as a polynomial in the above invariants.
- It is also simple to see that for a tensor of order $2N$ there are at least $n^N$ algebraic invariants, since the equation:
  $$\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_n = 1}^n A_{i_1 \dots i_n j_1 \dots j_n}\ v_{ j_1 \dots j_n } = \lambda\ v_{ i_1 \dots i_n}$$
  with $ v_{ j_1 \dots j_n }\neq 0$. It is still a problem of eigenvalues over a space of dimension $n^N$ and therefore that gives rise to a Cayley-Hamilton polynomial of degree $n^N$, whose coefficients must be algebraic invariants.
  However, the above is a very non-general procedure. In particular, it does not seem to be applicable to third-order tensors, or tensors of order $2N+1$. What about the algebraic invariants of a third-order tensor, for example?

Comment: With your definition of an invariant, your claim about 2-tensors is false. You have to require an invariant to be invariant under a suitable action of the general linear group.

Comment: What is "the" action that you are talking about? For instance, if you consider $(1,1)$ tensors you get one natural action and when you consider $(2,0)$ tensors, you get another natural action. But in both cases you have the order 2 tensors. In your question you identify both with square matrices (which is wrong) and consider the action by conjugation.

Comment: I am not nitpicking here, your your question is genuinely unclear. Classically (since the 19th century), people studied symmetric $(n,0)$ tensors on ${\mathbb C}^k$ where the action is by the "change of variables" which, in the case $n=2$ and identification of symmetric tensors with symmetric matrices $M$, is via $M\mapsto A^TMA$, $A\in GL(k)$. Your action is different. I do not understand which action do you consider, say, on $(2,1)$-tensors.

Comment: The action of GL(V) is the usual "change of coordinates" for tensors, probably the most typical action when dealing with tensor in practical applications (all my examples involve covarint tensors: type $(N,0)$)

Comment: The change of coordinates action on $(2,0)$-tensors is different from the one that you wrote.

Comment: In any case, whatever action you consider, there is Hilbert's theorem that the set of invariants is generated by a finite subset (Hilbert basis). There are algorithms for computation of Hilbert bases, but even in the case of symmetric $(n,0)$-tensors on $\mathbb C^k$ there is no known "general" answer.